# Odoo 10 - Split taxes in sale order

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

When products have different taxes (i.e. different VAT % values), Odoo group everything when displaying the tax in the total.

How can I get the subtotals for each tax (i.e. VAT 10%, VAT 20%, etc.)?

```xml
<t t-foreach="doc._get_tax_amount_by_group()" t-as="amount_by_group">
    <tr>
        <td><span t-esc="amount_by_group[0] or 'Taxes'"/></td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <span t-esc="amount_by_group[1]"
                  t-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": doc.pricelist_id.currency_id}'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</t>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some customization (of the form view) to display each Tax Group on the Quotation or Sales Order forms, but there is actually no customization needed to display multiple Tax Groups on the Quotation/Order PDF.

1. Enable Developer Mode
2. Go to **Accounting (or Invoicing) > Configuration > Accounting > Taxes
3. Open your Taxes record's form view
4. Click **Advanced Options**
5. Notice the **Tax Group** field

   - All lines that have Taxes are grouped into their Tax Groups, then summed up per group

---

For example, if we set up our Taxes entries like this:

- Tax (5%)

  - **Amount**: 5.00
  - **Tax Computation**: Percentage of Price
  - **Tax Group**: Tax (5%)

    - Manually created the Tax Group
- Tax (10%)

  - **Amount**: 10.00
  - **Tax Computation**: Percentage of Price
  - **Tax Group**: Tax (10%)

    - Manually created the Tax Group

We can create a Quotation or Sales Order such as this:

- Line 1

  - **Product**: Product A
  - **Quantity**: 1.0
  - **Unit Price**: 50.00
  - **Taxes**: 5%
- Line 2

  - **Product**: Product B
  - **Quantity**: 1.0
  - **Unit Price**: 100.00
  - **Taxes**: 10%

In the totals section of the Sales Order's form, the "Taxes" value will combine all taxes, regardless of their Tax Group.

- **Subtotal**: $150.00
- **Taxes**: $12.50
- **Total**: 162.50

However, if we click **Print > Quotation / Order**, then the PDF shows these results, with Taxes grouped by Tax Group:

- **Subtotal**: $150.00
- **Taxes (5%)**: $2.50
- **Taxes (10%)**: $10.00
- **Total**: $162.50